# Woocommerce: Add a free product when specific products are added to the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I would like to add a free product to the cart when a user add toa cart a product variation (defined from an array of variation IDs). And when the customer removes the variation product from the cart, the free product must be removed too.

I have this code snippet to add it in my theme's functions.php, but I got 2 errors:

1. The free product is not removed from cart when user removes the variation product.
2. Error messafe displayed in this screenshot
   [image]

The code I am using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );
function add_free_product_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $variation_ids = array( 68846, 68847, 68848 ); // Replace with your variation IDs
    $free_product_id = 78566; // Replace with your free product ID
    $found = false;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( in_array( $_product->get_variation_id(), $variation_ids ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $found ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
    } else {
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $free_product_id ) {
                $woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make variation Ids working within this code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is outdated and `woocommerce_add_to_cart` is not the right hook to be used, as it will not allow adding to cart the free product and will not handle when the user removes products from cart.

The following code will handle all product types IDs, **including variation IDs**.

When a product is added to cart ("defined" in an array of product IDs or/and variation IDs), a free product will be added to cart.

If the free product is in cart and there are no any "defined" products in cart, the free product will be removed from cart.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );
function add_free_product_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    // Here below add your product IDs or/and variation IDs in the array
    $targeted_ids     = array( 68846, 68847, 68848 ); 
    $free_product_id  = 78566; // <= Here set your free product ID
    $found_in_cart = $free_in_cart = false; // Initializing variables

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // handling product and variation IDs
        $cart_ids = array($item['product_id'], $item['variation_id']);

        // Check for matched products in cart
        if ( count( array_intersect( $cart_ids, $targeted_ids ) ) > 0) {
            $found_in_cart = true;
        } 
        // Check if the free product is in cart
        elseif ( in_array($free_product_id, $cart_ids) ) {
            $free_in_cart = $item_key ;
        }
    }

    // If a matched product is found and free product is not in cart
    if ( $found_in_cart && ! $free_in_cart ) {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id ); // Add free product
    } 
    // If there is no matched products and free product is in cart
    elseif ( ! $found_in_cart && $free_in_cart ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $free_in_cart ); // remove free product
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.